# How to configure and start Datastore when using cloud Datastore with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-datastore

I followed the tutorial from [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore).

1.Installed Cloud SDK
2.Downloaded getting-started-ruby/2-cloud-datastore source
3.Installed dependencies
4.Configured settings
5.Ran the app on my local machine(Win 7 x64)

In my web browser, enter this address :http://localhost:3000, then I got these errors:

> Faraday::SSLError in BooksController#index
>   SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
>       app/models/book.rb:24:in 'dataset'
>       app/models/book.rb:42:in 'query'
>       app/controllers/books_controller.rb:20:in 'index'

code in app/models/book.rb:24 :

```
@dataset ||= Google::Cloud::Datastore.new(
  project: Rails.application.config.
                 database_configuration[Rails.env]["dataset_id"]
)
```

I want to run this app on my local machine.
In my opinion, I need to configure Datastore.
But this tutorial didn't mention how to do this.

Should I configure Datastore in this app? How to do this?
If not, how to fix this problem?

Do I have to use `Datastore Emulator` to develop and test my application locally?

Comment: The error you're getting is a bad SSL cert.  Google Cloud isn't allowing your local to connect to it.

Comment: @bkunzi01 How to fix this? I'm not familiar with this error. Could you tell me directly or give me links about this error? Thank you.